# Multiply NSDecimalNumber with NSDecimalNumber return 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I know this kind of question shouldn't be asked. But, I stuck here for days without any clue. So, I really need help.

I have a core data object, let's say, products.

// Product
NSDecimalNumber *quantity
NSDecimalNumber *price

What I'm trying to do is summarize the price and set it to a label. I search and found some topic here said that NSDecimalNumber can't do standard match operation as it's an object that wrap the actual value. It has to be done through **decimalNumberByAdding** and **decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy**. So, I wrote the following code,

```
NSDecimalNumber *totalPrice = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:0.0];
[self.productArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Product *product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [totalPrice decimalNumberByAdding:[product.price decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:product.quantity]];
    NSLog(@"%@", totalPrice);
    NSLog(@"%@", totalPrice.doubleValue);
    NSLog(@"%@", totalPrice.decimalValue);
}];
```

None of those NSLog were showing correct result. They were showing neither 0 or NULL

But, if I NSLog the following code, the correct result can be shown.

```
[product.price decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:product.quantity]
```

Can you help me point out what do I miss here?

Comment: Make sure you are not multiplying by zero. NSLog your initial values before using them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not assigning the return value.

```
[totalPrice decimalNumberByAdding:[product.price decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:product.quantity]];
```

should be:

```
totalPrice = [totalPrice decimalNumberByAdding:[product.price decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:product.quantity]];
```

Since decimalNumberByAdding returns a value, does not update the variable automatically. Because of that, totalPrice is always 0, that's the value you assigned on init.